# Is it possible to create a hierarchical exposed filter in views using the Data module?

Tags: 7, database, views

I'm using [Data module](https://www.drupal.org/project/data) to adopt tables from the same DB as 'native' Drupal tables and [Views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to present the data.

I added two dropdown exposed filters with Selective filter module. It takes all values from fields and puts them to the selective list. It works fine.

However I would like to configure my exposed filters the way that the second filter will show values according to the chosen value in the first one. E.g. if you choose a specific academic department in the first filter, the second one will offer you the list of this department's staff members.

Is it possible to achieve such a behavior? If so, do I need any extra modules (taxonomy?) or should I create a module myself?

Comment: You can use Taxonomy itself. And use Better Exposed filter in Views to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

First Install [Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) Module for display taxonomy of parent/child relations then add that taxonomy as a field to your content type then add this field to your exposed filter. it's working..